# Angular/Typescript - Making call to method within return promise statement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I have created a component in Angular that reads an XML file and uses a parser to display it to the HTML table that the component has. Within the parsing method, I want to change the functionality of the displayed data by modifying certain aspects when they are reached in the read XML data, but whenever I try to make a call to the method that will return the changed data I receive an error stating:

"core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'CurrencyConvChange' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'CurrencyConvChange' of undefined".

This is the code for my main component's typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataStoreService } from '../../data-store.service';

@Component
({
  selector: 'app-tableofshares',
  templateUrl: './tableofshares.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tableofshares.component.css']
})

export class TableofsharesComponent
{
  public xmlItems: any;
  new_curr_value;
  test_1 = 1;
  test_2 = 1;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: DataStoreService)
  // tslint:disable-next-line: one-line
  {
    this.loadXML(); // Runs below function when the project is started.
  }

  async CurrencyConvChange(test_1, test_2)
  {
    console.dir("recieved test 1: " + test_1);
    console.dir("recieved test 2: " + test_2);
    return 0;
  }

  // Loads the data
  loadXML()
  {
    this.http.get('assets/Shares_Data.xml',
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method'),
      responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe((data) => {
      this.parseXML(data).then((data) =>
      {
        this.xmlItems = data; // Assigns xmlItems data from request
      });
    });
  }

  // Manipulates the data
  async parseXML(data)
  {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
      let k: string | number,
      arr = [],
      test_var,
      parser = new xml2js.Parser({trim: true, explicitArray: true});

      parser.parseString(data, function(err, result)
      {
        const obj = result.ShareList;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (k in obj.share)
        {
          const item = obj.share[k];
          const test_1 = item.sharePrice[0].currency[0];
          console.dir("test 1: " + test_1);

          const test_2 = item.sharePrice[0].value[0];
          console.dir("Test 2: " + test_2);

          this.CurrencyConvChange(test_1, test_2);

          arr.push
          ({
            title: item.title[0], companySymbol: item.companySymbol[0],
            numOfShares: item.numOfShares[0], lastShareUpdate: item.lastShareUpdate[0],
            currency: item.sharePrice[0].currency, value: item.sharePrice[0].value
          });
        }
        resolve(arr);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I'm making the call to my desired method in the line "this.CurrencyConvChange(test_1, test_2)" and am confused by the received error as I have already defined the method CurrencyConvChange before any of the others. I'm somewhat new to typescript and was wondering whether this was some sort of rule I was previously unaware of?

Comment: You should consider **NOT** mixing async with promise, it's better to choose one or the other and go all the way with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is neither related to typescript nor promises. This is related to `this` reference.

> You define a callback function

```
 parser.parseString(data, function(err, result)
```

> Inside that function you try to access to `this`

```
 this.CurrencyConvChange
```

But inside that function `this` refers to the call back function you define. Not to your component instance. If you want to point to the correct `this` use arrow function to define your callback like below :

```
 parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => ....
```

Or use an uglier workaround like below :

```
let that = this; // outside of function
// inside your function
that.CurrencyConvChange
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stupid fix that use often. In your class declare:

```
static _this: any;
```

In your constructor assign:

```
TableofsharesComponent._this = this;
```

Then you can call your function like so:

```
TableofsharesComponent._this.CurrencyConvChange(test_1, test_2).
```

If this is a bad idea I'd love to hear why so I can correct my code.